# Will SQL Server Management Studio run multiple statements synchronously?

Tags: sql, ssms, synchronous

I am trying to run three `delete` statements in SQL Server Management Studio, like this:

```
Delete from table1
Delete from table2
Delete form table3
```

Will those statements be executed line by line? Basically, I want table2 deletion to wait for table1 being finished, and table3 deletion waiting for table2 being finished.

Answer (score 1):

Sql management studio will not run multiple statements concurrently. It will run them one by one top down. For example your three delete statements; Line 1 will run, then Line 2 then line 3. They will not run concurrently at the same time.

Comment: To be more precise, unless they are separated by `GO`, they will be sent to the server as one batch. The server will execute them synchronously